# Find mass of solid bounded by cone $z = 2\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and plane $z=4$

Tags: integration, volume, spherical-coordinates, cylindrical-coordinates

Let S be the solid bounded by the cone $z = 2\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and plane $z=4$. Let S have mass $m$ and constant density $\rho_0$.

Express $\rho_0$ in terms of $m$ $\\$
Find the moment of inertia of S about the z axis and express it in terms of $m$

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. In order to get answers, please show what have you tried. Are you stuck on a particular point? What do you need help with?

Comment: So $m = \int \int \int \rho (xyz) dV $ of which becomes $m = \int \int \int \rho_0 r^2 \sin^2\phi d\phi d\theta dr$

Looking at the bounds $0 < r < 4, 0< \theta < 2\pi$ But I am not sure on the bounds of $\phi$ 

This link helped https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342478/find-volume-of-a-cone-z-k-sqrtx2y2-bounded-by-z-h-using-spherical-coord

of which I assume the bounds of $\phi$ are the same but not too sure. 

I then solve the triple integral and then rearrange to get $\rho_0$ in terms of m 

Of then for the second part of the question I would just solve $z = M_xy / m$ ?

Comment: Actually for the second question for moment of inertia I would solve
$$Iz = \int \int \int (x^2 + y^2) \rho_0 dV$$ ??

Comment: Also realised that my bounds for r should be $ 0<r<4/cos\phi$

Comment: You should try to use cylindrical coordinates instead. Transform $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$. $dV$ becomes $r dr d\theta dz$. You integrate $z$ between $0$ and $4$, $r$ between $0$ and $z/2$, and $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$. The last integral is easy, since you have circular symmetry.

Comment: Using cylindrical makes it so much easier. Thank you Andrei